# How do I use auto layout programmatically?

Tags: ios, layout, uiview

When I try to use auto layout like so:

```
CJGBoardLabels* labels = [CJGBoardLabels alloc];
[self.view insertSubview:labels aboveSubview:_mainBoard];
[_mainBoard addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[labels]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(labels)]];
```

I get this error:

```
2014-01-02 16:51:05.141 chess[18050:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requesting the window of a view (<CJGBoardLabels: 0xa6a8570; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>) with a nil layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.'
```

What's the appropriate way to programmatically use auto layout without calling initWithFrame?  Or do I still have to call initWithFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do

```
labels = [CJBoardLabels new];
```

or

```
labels = [[CJBoardLabels alloc] init];
```

or

```
labels = [[CJBoardLabels alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

In each case, followed by **(IMPORTANT)**

```
labels.translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Or, you could use [my lovely auto layout category](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout) and use

```
labels = [CJBoardLabels autolayoutView];
```

which does the above for you...and plenty of other goodies for creating your constraints in code.